# How do I override some neovim installation dependencies in nix config

Tags: nix, nixos

Hi I have currently an older version of `pynvim` in my nixos installation for neovim.
This `pynvim` is configured in nixpkgs-stable.
now I want to make use of the one in nixos-unstable since that's a newer version which I need to get a specific neovim pluging working (copilotchat.nvim)

I thought to fix this with an overlay.
this is my code for the overlay:

```
_: pkgs: {
  neovim-unwrapped = pkgs.neovim-unwrapped.overrideAttrs (
    oldAttrs: rec {
      neovim-unwrapped = pkgs.neovim-unwrapped.overrideAttrs {
        extraPython3Packages = [pkgs.unstable.python3Packages.pynvim pkgs.unstable.python3Packages.prompt-toolkit pkgs.unstable.python3Packages.requests];
      };
    }
  );
}
```

but I still only get the older version of `pynvim`.
if I use pkgs.unstable.neovim-unwrapped in my config I also get the older version of `pynvim`.

any help?

Comment: Seems weird to me that your are overriding the `neovim-unwrapped` attribute from `neovim-unwrapped`. I guess you should directly use `oldAttrs: rec { extraPythonPackages = [ ... ]; }`

Comment: I tried that before as well but that didn't work either.